# making a bottom border with a gradient for text

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to make a border-bottom with a gradient for and I tryed this:

```
h2{
    color: #16DB00;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF00C9;
    border-bottom-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,200,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,200,0) 100%);
}
```

and this is what I'm aiming for:

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCrJg.jpg)

It fades in to an 0% alpha not in to a black color

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

h2 {
  color: #16DB00;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 0, 200, 1), rgba(255, 0, 200, 0));
}
```

```html
<h2>test</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

Should you need to support IE9-10 the ::after Pseudo class allows use of another element to style. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/DanStevens/pen/pxMvqb).

```
h2 {
  color: #16DB00;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

h2::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,200,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,200,0) 100%);
}
```